# How to open a GUID formatted flash drive on a Windows 7 netbook?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I have a Mac which I have files on.

I put in a GUID formatted USB flash drive and dropped some files on to it.

I took the USB flash drive  and plugged in to my netbook that is running Windows 7.

It shows up in “Devices and Printers.” It also appears in  “Safely Remove Hardware.” But no actual letter or device for the USB flash drives shows up when I search for it in other ways.

How do I access the files of my GUID USB flash drive on my Windows 7 netbook?

Answer (score 1):

There's two things mixed up here:
Your flash drive is a GUID (GPT) volume, which is probably formatted as HFS+ (Mac OS X). The former is unproblematic in Windows 7, the latter isn't, because Windows doesn't natively suppoert HFS+.

There's two things you could do:

1. Get an HFS+ driver for Windows, see the [Wikipedia artice on HFS+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Windows) for a summary of your options. TL;DR: Read-only on Windows is easy, writing will cost you.
2. Format your flash drive with the FAT32 file system. That way, it can be read from and written to on all operating systems. Unfortunately, FAT32 ist rather antiquated and doesn't support file sizes greater than 4GB. But unless you're planning on trandsporting large files (such as movies in HD or images of full DVDs), you won't be in trouble.